# JavaFX| Label changing the window's background clolor

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to write up two CSS stylesheets for my application (light theme, dark theme). I have an existing stylesheet where I declare the global font, after that one, I set up the initial theme. This is how it looks, basically.

```
 primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 414, 896);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/font/globalFont.css").toExternalForm()); //sets the font
        scene.getStylesheets().add((getClass().getResource("css/theme/dark.css").toExternalForm()));
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

globalFont.css looks like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Inter V";;
    src: url("Inter.ttf");
}

.root{
    -fx-font-family: "Inter V";
}
```

and dark.css is as follows:

```
.root{
    -fx-text-color: #EDEEC0;
}

.label{
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-color;
}
```

My issue is, since I have a transparent stage and transparent background, adding a label there changes my window's background. Have a look - [image: Before adding label] [image: After adding label].

I just want to change the label's colour and keep the transparent backgrounds. I tried with using `Text` instead of `Label` but the colour isn't affected.

The `fxml` file looks like this:

```
<StackPane prefHeight="896.0" prefWidth="414.0" stylesheets="@css/theme/general.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.rtkay.App">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <top>
            <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="414.0" spacing="24.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <FontIcon iconLiteral="fltrmz-options-24" iconSize="24">
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </FontIcon>
                  <FontIcon iconLiteral="fltral-badge-24" iconSize="24">
                     <cursor>
                        <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                     </cursor>
                  </FontIcon>
                  <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="303.0" spacing="24.0">
                     <children>
                        <FontIcon iconLiteral="fltral-dark-theme-24" iconSize="24">
                           <cursor>
                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                           </cursor>
                        </FontIcon>
                        <FontIcon iconLiteral="fltral-broad-activity-feed-24" iconSize="24">
                           <cursor>
                              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                           </cursor>
                        </FontIcon>
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="16.0" left="16.0" right="16.0" top="16.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

`general.css` has one class to modify the size of the label (works just fine).

Also in `dark.css` why do I have to write up the `.label` class? Why doesn't `-fx-text-fill` in `.root` get inherited to every component?

Edit: I got it to work with `Text` instead of `Label`. I was using the wrong classname. `.Text` instead of `.text`. However I'd still like to know why the `Label` also changes the window color, if anyone has an answer for that.

Comment: If I recall correctly, JavaFX only loads the default user-agent stylesheet (`modena.css`) when the `Control` class is first initialized (and `Label` inherits from `Control`). The `modena.css` theme applies a background to the root node. You can add your own background color to `.root` in your stylesheet to override the default one. As for `-fx-text-fill` not being inherited, that's because that CSS property is, well, not inherited. Only a few are (e.g. font-related properties).

Comment: Ahh makes sense. Setting a bg color to root solves it. Thanks @Slaw

Comment: While `-fx-text-fill` is not inherited, the default value depends on a few "looked-up colors" (essentially CSS color variables), and the values of those *are* inherited. Those "looked-up colors" are `-fx-light-text-color` (used for text on dark backgrounds), `-fx-dark-text-color` (used for text on medium backgrounds) and `-fx-mid-text-color` (used for text on light backgrounds). So you should be able to achieve what you want by setting `-fx-light-text-color` and `-fx-mid-text-color` on `.root`.

Comment: Related (to background color part of the question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311541/javafx-just-declaring-nodes-changes-background-of-other-nodes

Comment: I had an idea that something else was being inherited but I hadn't thought that far yet.. Need to go back to the docs haha. But it's all clear now. Thanks for the help @James_D

Comment: Unfortunately, the docs don't really tell you enough. I usually end up referring to the [source code for modena.css](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css); have a look at the settings for `.root` and the comments (first 380 lines or so).

Comment: Just went through `modena.css`. It makes the docs really feel like you're just scratching the surface. Thanks again @James_D