# JavaFX -- when I create new instance of TextField whole window becomes white-ish

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I created JavaFX application, made whole screen black. Then I decided to add new instance of TextField to get input from user, but noticed that whole screen now is white-ish. I didn't even added it to any pane or scene. I tried to change TextField's background color to empty, but nothing removes white-ish color.

Here is code, that makes black window:

```
package org.medianik.tictactoe;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.InputStream;

import static org.medianik.tictactoe.util.Constants.*;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class TicTacToe extends Application{

    private static TicTacToe instance;
    public static TicTacToe getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    final Pane pane;

    public TicTacToe(){
        width = calculateWidth();
        height = calculateHeight();
        pane = new StackPane();
        instance = this;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }

    /**
     * The entry point
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        //In Constants.java:
        //public static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
        var scene = new Scene(pane, width, height, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        setupIcon(stage);
//        new TextField();

    }

    private int calculateWidth(){
        var bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        return Math.min((int) bounds.getWidth() - GLOBAL_OFFSET, MAX_WIDTH);
    }

    private int calculateHeight(){
        var bounds = Screen.getPrimary().getBounds();
        return Math.min((int) bounds.getHeight() - GLOBAL_OFFSET, MAX_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void setupIcon(Stage stage){
        InputStream inputIcon = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png");
        Image icon = new Image(inputIcon);
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("stop");
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }
}
```

And here is window:
[Picture of ordinary person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT2ud.png)
But if I uncomment one single line:

```
    /**
     * The entry point
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        //In Constants.java:
        //public static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
        var scene = new Scene(pane, width, height, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        setupIcon(stage);
        new TextField();

    }
```

Everything goes white-ish:
[Picture of insane one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMPmr.png)

Even if I make background *empty* nothing changes:

```
    /**
     * The entry point
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        var scene = new Scene(pane, width, height, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        setupIcon(stage);
        TextField text = new TextField();
        text.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
    }
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I feel like this question was asked and answered before.

Comment: Found a solution, described it in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66488204/javafx-when-i-create-new-instance-of-textfield-whole-window-becomes-white-ish#comment117575054_66491375) to answer

Answer (score 1):

Was a bit astonished to see this (and had no immediate answer ;) so did a bit of digging:

- verified that I can reproduce the different behavior in the (slightly stripped-down) example
- added debug print outs of pane's state before/after creating the TextField: noted that its background is null before and not-null after
- followed field creation in a debugger: noted styleSheet init on classLoading of Control

So the reason for the difference is that the default styleSheet is loaded in static code block of class Control (there might be other paths):

```
static {
    ... 
    // Ensures that the default application user agent stylesheet is loaded
    if (Application.getUserAgentStylesheet() == null) {
        PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet();
    }
}
```

Modified example:

```
public class TicTacToe extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        Pane pane = new StackPane();
        var scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 300, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        System.out.println("pane before styling: " + pane.getBackground()); 
        new TextField();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            System.out.println("pane after styling: "  + pane.getBackground()); 
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The rationale (which I’m not necessarily defending) is that the default style sheet only applies styles to controls. So applications that use no control subclasses at all typically don’t actually need the (not insignificant) overhead of the whole CSS subsystem. Loading the default style sheet in the static initializer in `Control` avoids this overhead for such applications, as I understand it.

Comment: interesting .. my first thought was: but Charts? On second thought: they draw in Label (at least), so implicitly load Control. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed in Stylesheet. As @Sedrick mentioned, yes, my problem was [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311541/javafx-just-declaring-nodes-changes-background-of-other-nodes#comment87639792_50311668) in other question, but i couldn't find it by search, so I asked a new one. I set the default stylesheet to STYLESHEET_CASPIAN and everything got back to normal.